# creating a lens for an iphone

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes, glass

How to create a lens for an iphone?

I finished most parts of that phone only one remaining is lens(glass) part of the phone

[image]

[image]

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGb3I.png)

As you see lens is looking a bit unrealistic I want it to look like something like this

[image]

Over all my lenses are sphere and my node is a simple principled BSDF
I want to know how to create lens and what to give to its node.

[image]

Comment: you can share your file on any cloud service - and post the link here. so e.g. dropbox. and yes, your blend file would help because we cannot see how you modelled it (geometry) and we don't know your materials.

Comment: some "general advice": if you have glass i would prefer using cycles for rendering because it looks a lot better than eevee.

Comment: It looks as if you had a single sphere as a lens. As you can already in your close up images of the real thing, they are much more complex. There are several layers of lenses and you can see a bit of that inside the cameras on your image. If you want it to look more realistic, I would ask Google for "iphone camera structure" or "phone camera structure".

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The material you have put on your lens is not suitable for a glass lens:

- Most important: you have *Metallic* set to 1, set it to 0 because glass is not metal and metal will never be transparent, no matter what you set as *Transmission* value - this will be ignored if the material is metal.
- The *Roughness* is at 0.5, a camera lens should have a very low roughness maybe between 0.0 and 0.05 (whereas 0.0 would be perfectly sharp glossy which it won't be in real life)
- You have set the *IOR* to 1.00 which means there is absolutely no refraction at all. Real glasses and especially lenses refract light, that's one of the important aspects of how they work in real life. The default 1.45 would be okay, although specific lenses may have varying values.
- Last but not least, the color is much too dark and saturated, this will not let very much light through the lens. Color on a transparent object looks much darker than on an opaque object (like your sphere was before).

Here is a comparison between your material and the changes I suggest. By the way, is the sphere a placeholder object or is this your lens? Because the phone lenses are not full spheres.

[image: lens material comparison]

Comment: hello thanks for your answer this is lens itself i dont know how to model lens nor i dont have any clue how phone lenses are suppose to be ill be grateful for a bit more guidance from you like what shape are they like and what are their materials here is my full camera part   [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=e8wOPsw6" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/e8wOPsw6/)

Comment: @khashayar I don't know exactly how they are shaped, I just know they are not spheres. I already told you to do a Google search on iphone camera structures. How did you model that camera part anyway? The mesh is a mess...

Comment: first i googled it and working on it already second we did model it in catia then export it to blender is something wrong with my camera part ?